# Calculate the time taken for the whole journey given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

**MyApproach:**

Without stoppage, distance travelled is $54$Km in 1hr.Now due to stoppage train travels $45$Km in 1hr.

Now time taken for the whole journey=Distance/speed

> I am confused how to use these equations.
>
> Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is the objective to calculate how much time the train is stationary throughout the whole journey? Or is the objective to calculate how much time the train travels throughout the whole journey?

Comment: @BLAZE I think it id the stoppage time which is the formar one which you said.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the train travels $99$Km altogether but we wish to calculate how much time the train is stationary for. If I have understood the question correctly here is the speed vs time graph for the situation: [image]

$$ \mathrm{Total} \space \mathrm{time} = T = \cfrac{\mathrm{distance}}{\mathrm{speed}}= \cfrac{54}{1}+ t+\cfrac{45}{1} $$

$$  T =  54+ t +45 $$
$$  T =   t + 99 \tag{1}$$

Where $t$ is the time for which the train is stationary and this time is represented by the gap on the time axis between the two coloured lines.

This problem cannot be solved as you have an equation $(1)$ with $2$ unknowns $t$ and $T$, therefore need more data to solve it.

Comment: I think for 9Km is the stoppage distance and speed would be ?I am confused here.

Comment: @justin What do you mean by stoppage distance? Is this train decelerating?

Comment: it looks like in the question it is given.

Comment: @justin I'm sorry, I don't think this can be solved, I need more data

Comment: @justin If it could be solved then someone would have already done it, the question has been asked over 1 hour ago.